# How do I set the parameter for the passed function in typescript using generics?

Tags: javascript, typescript, function, types, parameters

In below code in function `resHandler()`, `res` is type any. But I passed the type when calling `sendRequest()`. Shouldn't `res` is of type 'PersonType' automatically?

```js
type PersonType = {
    name: string;
    age: number;
}
async function sendRequest<T>(resFn: (data: T)=> void){
  const res = await fetch('some-url');
  let data: T = await res.json();
  resFn(data);
}

sendRequest<PersonType>(resHandler)

function resHandler(res){
  console.log(res)
}
```

Thanks for the help.

`res` in `resHandler()` to automatically receive the data type assigned in `sendRequest()`.

Comment: "*Shouldn't res is of type 'PersonType' automatically?*" it's not a generic function. The type of the parameter is thus only whatever it was at declaration time. Since you didn't supply one, it's `any` implicitly.

Comment: In this scenario, what do I have to do get the type of the `res` in `resHandler` automatically?

Comment: You can't, that's not how TS function declarations work.  There's no contextual typing that reaches back across arbitrary control flow.  It's like buying a random pair of shoes and then wondering how they can be automatically sized to your feet.  That's not how it works; the shoes don't know what size your feet are going to be.

Comment: Is this [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? Why should the type be inferred *inside* `resHandler`? You're only passing strings. It would make sense for it to only work with strings. If it has to work with other types, then you need to make sure the code handles it. `resHandler<T>(res: T) { return res.toLowerCase(); }` won't work with `resHandler(42)` for example.

Comment: @jcalz then what is the best way to assign types in this situation?

Comment: Tell a shoe store employee what size your feet are.  Oh, I mean [annotate your function parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#parameter-type-annotations).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In this scenario, what do I have to do get the type of the res in resHandler automatically?

You can't.

Typescript will *not* look at how a value is used to determine it's type.

Instead, it does it the other way. It verifies that how a value is used is allowed for how the type was declared.

What if you hade this?

```
sendRequest<PersonType>(resHandler)

const someResponse: SomeOtherType = getJson('...')
resHandler(someResponse) // What should the type of the argument be here?
```

Would you expect the `resHandler` argument type to change to `res: PersonType | SomeOtherType`? Typescript has decided you should not expect that.

---

So that means that typescript looks at this first:

```
function resHandler(res){
  console.log(res)
}
```

And it sees no type for `res`, so it infers `any` (which may be an error if `noImplicitAny` is enabled).

Then after that it checks to make sure everywhere that `resHandler` is used is compatible for this interface.

---

So to make this work without having to manually type the `res` parameter, you could inline the function:

```
sendRequest<PersonType>((res) => console.log(res.name)) // fine
```

Here the usage is linked to the declaration because the function is created in the context of `T extends PersonType`, so Typescript knows that `typeof res extends PersonType` as well.

Or you could manually type the argument if you want to work with `PersonType` directly.

```
function resHandlerForPerson(res: PersonType){
  console.log(res.name)
}

sendRequest<PersonType>(resHandlerForPerson) // fine
sendRequest<{ someOtherType: string }>(resHandlerForPerson) // type error
```

Now you have a `resHandlerForPerson` function that only works for a `PersonType` and will be a type error if you try to use to handle a response for any other type.

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.2.0-beta#code/C4TwDgpgBAChBOBnA9gOwCrmgXigbwFgAoKUqVAQwFsIAuKRYeAS1QHMBuYsqCtu8gFcqAIwRciAX2IVEIVAGMoAM0GLgzNAwioAJgCUIAR0ERGAHnQA+ABTwzAMVT0buisAr10ASmxWoAG7IzLrehCRQCmiMUPaIULgUAO4UzMAqEMAKABY2AOQoNAC0gvAANnneEqRlmVBuHl4JvClpsWYAdABWKKg2VdztiE6u7hQDUsTEiDoGxqYWcEhomJC2dmbeCf5RqCi1HWXIbBuIHZQ03lsA9NcqrBDTs4YmZsDmS72rELZxABIUPS1eAOZDwT5oG53ZQPJ56F4Ld54BjIGgAeWA2QQ33ojBY7Cgkl+ZgBQIQoPBCF6UKgoEgUAQ8DBUyIqnUmlQQ1JumBFIhfTi9H53zCg12+wgh2Op3O1Ag3mIkiAA)